# Converting address to geo-coordinates in Python

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, geopy

I am new to Python. I used geopy to convert inputted address to latitude and longitude. However, it is not working for all addresses(especially, specific ones including building names etc, like '204 West Rancho Blanco Road, Alamo, TX 78516') but it works fine for 'Keller, Texas'. Is there a more accurate and reliable way?
I tried using google api but it errors out that api_key is not found.
Please give me inputs

Comment: Which geocoder you have used? Can you update you post to show the code?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Geocode API is helpful in this case. But for sending a request you need to have an API Key. you can get one from [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY).

After you have your Key you can send  requests. The following example requests the latitude and longitude of "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA"

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You should replace YOUR_API_KEY with your API Key in the above link.

Comment: Thanks Amir.I will check that out